# Why does monitor show no tests found when there are tests in each GET/POST request?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, postman, monitoring

When I run my Postman monitor it says there are no tests available, even though I have created a single test in the request.
Is this referring to some other type of test?
Have attached both images
[Postman monitor error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdB9J.png)

[Developed test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv4wz.png)

Comment: make sure your reqeust are saved

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue.
Monitor is an online feature and is only available in workspaces.
I suspect the workspace is in Postman so it has issues to invoke my company's network which is protected with firewall. I tried to turn on and off the proxy but still have the issues.
I feel the newman may work which needs more efforts to implement.

Comment: This can be a comment to an answer.

Comment: I just got the ability to comment :-) Didn't have enough power to comment.

Comment: I will try newman but looks like it needs more efforts on programming so an BA can't do that.
I will also try JMeter - if will definitely work but also not a very quick and easy way.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31219856)

Comment: [Update] There are lots of limitations on Postman monitor and newman, especially if you have proxies. I finally resolved it with cURL, batch script and Jenkins pipeline. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons. The reasons are mentioned well in official doc.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/monitoring-your-api/troubleshooting-monitors/

According to my experience, you should not define "pm.response.json()" command as globally, you need to define it in test function (pm.test()) because saved global variables are not supported in monitors.